# Create new rtf file as a service on MacOS

Tags: macos, service, rtf

I regularly use this service to create a new text file in the currently opened folder:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set txt to make new file at (the target of the front window) as alias
    select txt
end tell
```

But it would be much more useful if I could create an RTF instead. Yet after googling and GPT'ing, I can't get it to work. Anyone that has written a similar service for themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not super elegant but you can write the data of an empty RTF document to your newly-created file:

```
tell application "Finder" to set txt to (make new file at Finder window 1) as alias
try
    set fileHandle to open for access (POSIX path of txt) with write permission
    write "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf2757
\\cocoatextscaling0\\cocoaplatform0{\\fonttbl}
{\\colortbl;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;}
{\\*\\expandedcolortbl;;}
\\paperw11900\\paperh16840\\margl1440\\margr1440\\vieww11520\\viewh8400\\viewkind0
}" to fileHandle
    close access fileHandle
on error err number num
    display dialog err & " number " & num buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "File I/O Error..." with icon caution
    try
        close access fileHandle
    end try
    return
end try

tell application "Finder" to select txt
```

This will result in a functioning RTF if you open it in TextEdit.